# Symfony2 - "No route found for "GET Instagram:instagramLoginStatus"

Tags: symfony, instagram

I'm integrating Instagram in the symfony2 website.

Here is the steps that i have followed

Install this bundle as usual by adding to composer.json:

"oh/instagram-bundle": "dev-master"
Register the bundle in app/AppKernel.php:

// app/AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    return array(
        // ...
        new Oh\InstagramBundle\OhInstagramBundle(),
    );
}
```

Add the following line to app/config/config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: @OhInstagramBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }
And if you're OK with the provided routes, add these to app/config/routing.yml

OhInstagramBundle:
    resource: "@OhInstagramBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Then I have created Instagram Client.

then i tried to load login button of instragram in webpage by including following line in twig file

{% render "OhInstagramBundle:Instagram:instagramLoginStatus" %}

Below is the error I'm getting

"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No route found for "GET Instagram:instagramLoginStatus"") in /var/www/html/source/venkat_rsi/portal/src/Knetik/UserBundle/Resources/views/Security/ajaxLogin.html.twig at line 68."

Do any one know why this error is coming? I'm new to symfony2.

This is the bundle I'm using 
https://github.com/ollietb/OhInstagramBundle

Comment: Have you updated security.yml as well?

Comment: Have you actually updated `app/config/routing.yml`? Or just pasted `And if you're OK with the provided routes,...` into `app/config/config.yml`?

Comment: I have updated every config and routing files. not just pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use render, use render controller or url, like this:

```
   {{ render(controller('OhInstagramBundle:Instagram:instagramLoginStatus')) }}
```

And look at this update https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md